# How to provide horizontal scroll for all listview Items?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

Actually what i need is when ever the user scrolls the list item horizontally, all the items in the listview should be scrolled.

Answer (score 0):

use **RecyclerView** from the **Appcompat** library. You can find the horizontal scrolling

```
RecyclerView mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
mCrimes = CrimeLab.get(getActivity()).getCrimes();
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(new CrimeAdapter());
```

Comment: I have a vertical scroll list view, when user swipes/scroll Horizontally  any item in the vertical scrollable listview then all vertical items should scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , you can do that

go for below link i guess what you need is there !!

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Implementing-a-Horizontal-ListView-Guide

Happy coding !!

Comment: my listview is also having the vertical scroll, when user scroll any item horizontally all vertical list items also scroll horizontally.

Comment: Okay, so what you need  !!

Answer (score 0):

you can do that, i test is work:

```
//first: regist Listener
hScrollView.setOnTouchListener(new scroll(hScrollView));


//second: loop ListView child, and setScrollX for each HorizontalScrollView
        class scroll implements OnTouchListener{
        HorizontalScrollView hScrollView;

        scroll(HorizontalScrollView view){
            this.hScrollView = view;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Scroll X = "+ hScrollView.getScrollX());

                int x = hScrollView.getScrollX();
                for(int i=0; i<managerList.getChildCount(); i++){
                    View view = managerList.getChildAt(i);
                    HorizontalScrollView scrollView = (HorizontalScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_scroll);
                    scrollView.setScrollX(x);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

hope can help you.

Comment: What is R.id.list_scroll? and in which xml file I need to put this HorizontalScrollView?

Comment: R.id.list_scroll is a HorizontalScrollView, i use <include> tag include to my ListView item layout: 
'<LinearLayout>
      //...other content
      <include 
        android:id="@+id/list_scroll"
        layout="@layout/manager_list_scroll"/>
 </LinearLayout>'

Comment: scroll cannot be resolved to a type, What should I do for solve this?

Comment: @layout/manager_list_scroll just a XML file name, inside i used HorizontalScrollView